# Visualizing multi-class ROC Analysis

Tags: r, logistic-regression, roc, multinomial

I am running a multinomial logistic regression model (with 3 possible outcomes) in R. I am trying to find the best way to assess the predictive power/accuracy of the model, and the best thing I've come up with is using a ROC curve.

For multi-class ROC analysis, I know that there is the one vs. one comparison or the one vs. all comparison. For the one vs. one comparison, would I need three separate ROC curves for each possible combination of outcome comparisons? If so, do I need to make a third model for comparing the two outcomes that were initially being compared to the baseline outcome?

For one vs. all comparison is the threshold for a r "random model" now 33% instead of 50%?

And finally, is there a better way to go about doing this/visualizing it?

EDIT: I know the pROC package has a multiclass.roc function, but I don't totally get what it does.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. It really has to do with evaluating the fit of a statistical model. Thus it seems like a better fit for [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Brier scores might be a better idea for a multi-class forecast. It's a proper scoring rule, and it naturally applied to multi-class situations.